# I want to create a table reporting results from two separate regressions using different variables

Tags: stata

I have run two regressions on similar but different data sets and regressors the results of which I want to report next to each other for comparability but keep them in one table using estout/esttab. The finished product should look something like this.

```
                 Table
-----------------------------------------
Dep. Var.:         a

-----------------------------------------
Regression 1       |Regression 2
                   
-----------------------------------------
x_1          coeff.|x_2         coeff.

y_1          coeff.|y_2         coeff.

z_1          coeff.|z_2         coeff.

l_1          coeff.|

m_1          coeff.|

-----------------------------------------
Obs           value|Obs      value

----------------------------------------- 
Hypothesis         |

x_1=1,p-value      |x_2=1,p-value 

    

-----------------------------------------
```

I am able to create individual tables like this just fine but I have honestly no idea where to start here and documentation hasn't been very helpful either. I hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the eststo/esttab syntax will help. Here's code which I think produces what you're after:

```
ssc install estout, replace
sysuse auto, clear

eststo m1: regress price mpg 
test mpg=1
estadd scalar pvalue = r(p)
eststo m2: regress price mpg trunk [enter image description here][1]
test trunk=1
estadd scalar pvalue = r(p)

esttab m1 m2, b(3) se(3) stats(pvalue r2 N, fmt(3 3 0) label("P-value" "R-squared" "Observations")) mtitle("Regression 1" "Regression 2") nocons
```

It creates this table:

```
--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
             Regression 1    Regression 2   
--------------------------------------------
mpg              -238.894***     -220.165** 
                 (53.077)        (65.593)   

trunk                              43.559   
                                 (88.719)   
--------------------------------------------
P-value             0.000           0.633   
R-squared           0.220           0.222   
Observations           74              74   
--------------------------------------------
Standard errors in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

The [esttab guide](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/esttab.html) is really great.